# Is there a way for me to cast a Future of a subtype to a Future of a supertype?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface as follows:

```
ConnectorInterface<C extends ChannelInterface>
```

An implementation as follows:

```
ConcreteConnector implements ConnectorInterface<ConcreteChannel>
```

A function as follows:

```
public <C extends ChannelInterface> Future<C> createChannel(ConnectorInterface<C>)
```

Is there some way for me to use this `createChannel()` method using the `ConcreteConnector` but cast the result as `Future<ChannelInterface>`?

Comment: Why not make `Future<ChannelInterface>` the return type of `createChannel`? It should be that simple.

Comment: @ernest_k None of those are under my control.  I am simply using these pre-existing interfaces and function.

Comment: Well, you can't write `Future<ChannelInterface> f = createChannel(new ConcreteConnector())`, but you can write `ChannelInterface f = createChannel(new ConcreteConnector()).get()`

Comment: Yes, but that beats the whole point of having a Future.  I'm doing this for now to get it to work: ```ConnectorInterface c = new ConcreateConnector();  Future<ChannelInterface> = createChannel(c);```.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on the intended implementation? Are you trying to return a `Future<ChannelInterface>` object from a method? Based on what you want to do, there may be alternative approaches.

Comment: Yes, I pass that future in to another method that takes Future<ChannelInterface>.  I control that other class (which has that method I call) though, and I'm realizing maybe the best way is for me to genericize it.  So, instead of dealing with Future<ChannelInterface>, I should genericize that class so it deals with: ```<T> Future<T extends ChannelInterface>```.

Comment: Makes sense. And given that it's a method parameter, you can even afford to make the method take `Future<? extends ChannelInterface>` (as `T` wouldn't be absolutely necessary) - but that depends on how argument is used.